# What is a Scorecard Custom Set Formula and how do I use it?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, dashboard-designer-2013, kpi

When creating a Scorecard which includes a KPI, in the right "Details" frame, there is a section for "Set Formulas" and under that (along with Time, which I understand) is "Custom" which I can't find any documentation for. How can and how do I use this? (I am using tabular data sources, if that matters.)